# Require gems according to Sinatra environment

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra

Considering the following Sinatra application...

## List of gems

```
# Gemfile

source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'sinatra',                    '~> 1.4.4'

group :production do
  gem 'rack-ssl',                 '~> 1.3.3'
end
```

## The app

```
# app.rb

require 'sinatra'
require 'rack/ssl'

configure :production do
  use Rack::SSL
end

get '/hi' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

...I'm wondering what is the best way to avoid to require the `rack/ssl` gem in development and test environments (because used in production only).

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just do this?

```
configure :production do
  require 'rack/ssl'
  use Rack::SSL
end
```

Comment: That's right. BTW, is it better than: `require 'rack/ssl' if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'production'`?

Comment: Yes, I see no advantages in the other form over this.